# What are the key differences between kendo and kenjutsu?

Tags: sword, style, kendo, kenjutsu

I was wondering what are the key differences between kenjutsu and kendo?

I know that kendo is considered as an art of fighting where as the kenjutsu is the art of killing, or am I wrong here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Kenjutsu* is the skill of using the sword, divided into various styles by *ryuha* (roughly, "schools"). This can include skills such as drawing (*iai*) or engaging (*battou*), as well the disarming of an armed opponent (*shinken shirahadome* or *muto dori*). Generally (though certainly not in all cases), *kenjutsu* is one component of a greater curriculum within a *ryuha* and is taught as a means to kill an opponent.

*Kendo* is a martial art with sport-like elements of competition. It originated in the 18th c. with the development of *shinai* and *bogu* as training tools for students of *kenjutsu*, and was changed heavily by the banning of militaristic activities following WWII when, in 1950, it was reintroduced into public life as "Shinai Competition" (*shinai kyougi*), then in 1952 was again renamed to *kendo* under the governance of the "All Japan Kendo Federation" (*Zen Nihon Kendo Renmei* or ZNKR). Modern *kendo* is much heavier in competition, whereas the origins of the art were a means of practicing the skills of *kenjutsu* in a safe manner (using *shinai* [bamboo sword] and *bogu* [armor]).

*Kendo* has much stronger philosophical ties to Buddhism than *kenjutsu* on its own. While specific *ryuha* teaching *kenjutsu* may have religious or philosophical views, concepts of *mushin*, *fudoshin*, and *zanshin* (all related to the doctrine of *Fudo Myo-o*) are essential to the practice of *Kendo*.

Answer (score 7):

Your question may be answered more generically as thus:

***What is the difference between -do and -jutsu?*** (with the exception of judo and jujutsu)

*-Jutsu*, grossly, means 'technique'. It means something applicable, practical, extremely concerned with getting results.

*-Do*, grossly, means 'path'. It has much stronger ties to a lot of other aspects of life, including but not limited to social and spiritual.

As a summary, you may find interesting to note that budo and bujutsu, on wikipedia, refer to the [same article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bud%C5%8D) - Budo. Here is the key point from this article, related to the difference:

*Budo and bujutsu have quite a delicate difference; whereas bujutsu only gives attention to the physical part of fighting (how to best defeat an enemy), budo also gives attention to the mind and how one should develop oneself.*

Any further talk would just be expanding on this sentence.