# What is Fudo Myo-o (concepts of mushin, fudoshin, and zanshin)?

Tags: aikido, kenjutsu, philosophy

[stslavik](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/users/25/stslavik) in [an answer related to Kenjutsu](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/a/677/82) mentions the concepts of *mushin*, *fudoshin*, and *zanshin* as part of Fudo Myo-o.  While I am somewhat familiar with all three, I am seeking a more in depth explanation as to how they relate to *kenjutsu* and *aikido*.

Comment: If there's something you're still feeling isn't answered, let me know. I really simplified a lot of texts and lessons down to a couple hundred words.

Comment: @stslavik: Your answer is pretty clear and gives me plenty to follow on through.  Thank you. I was familiar with the *zanshin* part and somewhat with *mushin* (from *mushin, mugamae*) but was in the dark as to the rest and did not know the links.  I do now ^_~

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're asking a lot of interconnecting but separate questions. Depending upon the view and the school, you will generally get different answers, but in *Mikkyo* (Esoteric Buddhism), these concepts (*Fudōshin*, *Mushin*, and *Zanshin*) are all derived from the teachings of *Fudō Myō-ō*. There is an order to these things, as I was taught it, so I will answer in that [relatively descending] order, attempting to keep it as simple as possible.

***Who Is*** Fudō Myō-ō?

*Fudō Myō-ō* is the Japanese name of [Acala, one of the Five Wisdom Kings of the Womb Realm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acala). His name in Japanese roughly translates to "Immovable Wisdom King", is the patron of the [*Yamabushi*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamabushi), and, according to [*Shingon* Buddhism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shingon), is not technically a Buddha. *Fudō Myō-ō* is the destroyer of delusion and a principal protector of Buddhism, and is the "Immovable Wisdom King" for his mind being forever unmoved. He carries a sword in his right hand, to cut away delusions and ignorance, and a rope in his left hand to bind violent and uncontrolled passions or "evil forces").

***What is*** Fudōshin?

*Fudōshin* is the immovable mind; calm, serene, perfectly stable, and unchanged. It is a state of equanimity, and imperturbability and acceptance of the present moment. It can be viewed that both *Mushin* and *Zanshin* are aspects of *Fudōshin*.

***What is*** Mushin?

*Mushin* is the state of no mind, or the mind unfettered by ancillary or superfluous thoughts. It is the mind in the moment, clear and unobstructed.

***What is*** Zanshin?

*Zanshin* is the state of the remaining mind; the mind maintained in the moment, relaxed but alert. While many martial arts attempt to "grade" *zanshin* by looking for the continued ready stance, this is not indicative of the minds awareness. Instead, the mind in *zanshin* has overcome an impediment and is ready for another, while still remaining in the present moment. This is sometimes called "relaxed awareness".

***What is the Mind?***

I've purposely left this for last in the discussion of *Fudō Myō-ō*: the mind referred to above is not the mind (in a philosophical, *cogito ergo sum* sense) necessarily as we think of it, but rather the Buddha Nature – the capacity for sentient beings to become Buddhas.

***The relationship to*** Kenjutsu *and* Aikido

It is incorrect to say that these concepts relate to *kenjutsu*. *Kenjutsu* is a broad category, comprised of various different arts (For example, *Kukishin-ryu kenpo*, *Niten-Ichi-ryu Nito Seiho*, and *Yagyu Shinkage-ryu Kenjutsu* are all individual styles of *kenjutsu* with different philosophies). Schools of *kenjutsu* with ties to Buddhism may teach some or all of the aforementioned virtues, each with different takes on the importance. Further, it is not necessary that it be a sword art for them to be viable (*Fudōshin*, for example, is taught as an important aspect of the *taijutsu* of *Shinden Fudō-ryu*). *Fudō Myō-ō* is commonly revered, however, in Japanese martial arts for the stillness of his mind.

*Aikido*, being derived from training in *Daitō-ryu Aikijujutsu* which in turn likely developed a great deal of its *taijutsu* ("body skills", which includes positioning [*taisabaki*]) from the *taijutsu* of *Kashima Shinden Jikishinkage-ryū Kenjutsu* and *Ono-ha Ittō-ryu Kenjutsu*, likely took a great deal of the Buddhist teachings popular among Samurai of its ancestor schools. When I studied *aikido* in an *aikikai* school, I never heard more than *mushin* ever talked about.

***References***

[*Shingon: Japanese Esoteric Buddhism*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0877734437) - *Yamasaki Taiko*
[*Shingon Buddhism: Theory and Practice*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0914910108) - *Kiyota Minoru*